# How to access redux state array property within reducer without iterating through state

Tags: reactjs, redux

The following code increments a value within a reducer. I'm wanting to know if their is a better approach of doing this instead of iterating through an array then setting the property from there.

```
action.data = the post id
```

**reducer**

```
case POST_LIKE_SUCCESS:        
      let newVote2 = {...state}
      console.log(newVote2.images)
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.map((image, idx) => {
          const disLike = parseInt(newVote2.images[idx].likeCount) + 1
          // instead of referring to [0] well just use idx 

          if (image.id === action.data) {
            return {
              ...image,
              user: {...image.user},
              likeCount: disLike

            };
          }
          return image;
        }),

      };
```

likeCount is the property i want easy access too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the structure of `store.images` to be an `Object`, keyed by the id and value set to the image. Then in the reducer, you can just look it up using `images[action.data]`.

When you're passing it down into a component and need an array, you can use `Object.values(state.images)` along with a [memoized selector](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) so it's only recomputed if the `images` object actually changes.

Comment: could you show a github example of how this could thi be implemented, tutorial, reference or something that could help me better see an example of this.